# Convergence of a sequence using consecutive difference

Tags: real-analysis

denote $(a_n)$ as a sequence. If the consecutive difference tend to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity, do it mean that $(a_n)$ converges? I feel like it should mean so but I am struggling to see a clear cut proof

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, consider
$$a_{n}=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac{1}{i}.$$
Clearly $a_{n+1}-a_{n}=\frac{1}{n+1}$ tends to $0$, but $a_{n}$ diverges to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $a_n=\log(n)$ if you take the limit for large $n$ then I think it is fairly clear that $a_n$ diverges. In that limit $a_n - a_{n-1} =\log\frac{n}{n-1}\rightarrow 0$